# Need help in Installing Ubuntu on Laptop with Secureboot

Tags: 14.04, windows, uefi, secure-boot

I just purchased HP G049AU whose configuration is :
- AMD A8
- 4 GB RAM

I checked that secureboot is enabled. I want to completely remove Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04.1
I would like to know :

- Can I install Ubuntu without disabling secureboot ?
- If it is mandatory to disable secureboot, then what are the steps ?

Plz help. Windows is pain to my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you can't. You need to install Ubuntu 12.04.2 or 12.10 in order to install using UEFI.

Here you have 2 tutorials:

http://www.howtogeek.com/175641/how-to-boot-and-install-linux-on-a-uefi-pc-with-secure-boot/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Have a nice day!

Comment: I didn't disabled secureboot & just changed boot priority in BIOS & it did boot Ubuntu 14.04. Does that mean, it's okay to not disable UEFI ?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to summarize.

Secureboot is normally turned off, for Ubuntu install. It has no purpose for Ubuntu, as it is a feature used by the junk that is Windows to prevent firmware from being altered by malware.

1). Make sure you run the "Recovery Backup Tool" present on all newer Windows systems. This will produce a set of DVD's which can rebuild the entire system to factory fresh state. Normally you may need from 2-5 DVD's, depending on the manufacturer.

This tool has differing names because each manufacturer calls it something else. I would prefer they call it "Systems Recovery Tool" and standardize this mess. At the entry point in the "RUN" Charm , type 'recovery' and you should see the tool listed in the output.

Please make sure you have a backup of your personal files, so that you can move them to Ubuntu.

2). You can then use the Live Install DVD of 14.04 to install Ubuntu. Just select the option to replace everything on the drive with Ubuntu. This will erase and consolidate all partitions on the drive, reparation the drive for Ubuntu, then install Ubuntu.

Make sure you click-on the check-boxes for 3rd party drivers, and extra packages and any additional updates from the Internet (making sure you are on the Internet before you install, by signing onto your WIFI if required, from the Live-DVD). Takes roughly 45-60 minutes, ending in a restart into Ubuntu desktop, and a normal system setup.

I hope this info is useful. Have fun and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

refer to ：
[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

this may help you.
I know my classmate has installed ubuntu 14.04 on his machine,which is uefi,by disable the secure boot and fast boot.

Comment: I didn't disabled secureboot & just changed boot priority in BIOS & it did boot Ubuntu 14.04. Does that mean, it's okay to not disable UEFI ?